# Clearinteval doesnot work

Tags: javascript

Clearinterval doesnot work inside condition in success
Code is like:

```
var threadComplete;
    function doc_creation() {
                $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("generateDoc")',
                dataType: "json",
                mtype: "post",
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("show modal");
                    threadComplete = setInterval(function () { checkDocGen() }, 3000);
                }
            });
        }
            function checkDocGen() {
                $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("callThreadSleep")',
                dataType: "json",
                mtype: "post",
                async: true,
                data: { ids: download_id },
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;     //   clearInterval(threadComplete); If i put here then it works        
                    if (data != true) {
                        clearInterval(threadComplete); //it executes but still call threadcomplete
                        console.log("hide");
                        if (data == "") {
                            $("#alert_doc_err").slideDown().delay(5000).slideUp();
                        } else {
                            window.location.href = data;
                        }
```

but If I put `clearInterval()` in success 1st line that it will work..any idea or any change ?

Comment: Pretty obviously - `data == true`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum that is the condition only..I want to clearInterval when data!=true..it execute clearInterval but still call `threadComplete`

Comment: You mean "*in success 1st line*" before the `debugger;` statement?

Comment: Using intervals with Ajax calls is normally a bad idea.

Comment: Where is `threadComplete` actually declared, and are both those functions actually next to each other as you've presented in your question - or are they possibly in different scopes with different `threadComplete` variables?

Comment: @JamesThorpe plz check updated question

Comment: @Bergi yes..check updated question

Comment: Well then @Benjamin's first comment holds, and that it's not making it into that `if` statement.

Comment: @JamesThorpe condition works perfectly..`true` is just a value..it goes into `if` statement

Comment: Do you get the console.log("hide") to run? If you don't, then you're not making it into the if-statement, as many above me already told you. But if you do get the console.log to appear, something else is wrong indeed.

Comment: @Niddro yes I am getting hide in console..

Comment: Then something else is going on unrelated to the intervals.

Comment: Did it..used `settimeout` instead of `setinterval`

Comment: Try to remove the `debugger;` statement.

Comment: Your'e calling the function multiple times but your interval variable is global.

Comment: @Bergi that doesnot effect

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum But I have to use it in another function..so what can be other possibility